# How to replace the Gutenberg default block with a custom block?

Tags: block-editor

I need to replace the Gutenberg default block (paragraph) with a custom block. In particular, every new post should start with the custom block instead of the default paragraph, and more generally the default block should substitute the default paragraph in every case a new paragraph is created/appended.

I guess the custom block would need a paragraph-like interface, but that's not a problem as my custom block is largely based on the `core/paragraph` itself.

#### Things I've tried

`setDefaultBlockName` [(docs)](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-blocks/#setDefaultBlockName)

It just doesn't work, see this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15730). Funnily enough, calling `getDefaultBlockName` immediately after setting it returns the custom block as expected, but apparently nothing else changes. I guess the functionality is just missing.

Comment: It looks like they may have addressed it in this comment - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15730#issuecomment-617853036

Comment: Yeah that's always me :)